# pdf form calculating time differences by jacascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

i'm trying me in scripting pdf forms.

I have writen a code for giving out a rounded time difference between two given times.

```
// define names for in and output
var inputFields = ["startTime", "endTime"];
var outputField = "totalTimeDiff";

// read inputfields
var startTimeString = this.getField(inputFields[0]).valueAsString;
var endTimeString = this.getField(inputFields[1]).valueAsString;

// covert to dataobjects
var startTime = util.scand("HH:MM", startTimeString);
var endTime = util.scand("HH:MM", endTimeString);

// calculate difference
var timeDiff = endTime - startTime;

// covert to hours
var hours = timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60);

// rounding
var roundedHours = Math.round(hours * 100) / 100;

// give out in textfield
this.getField(outputField).value = roundedHours.toString();
```

But in the converting to dateobjects the return is null even if the return of endTimeString and startTimeString is in the correct format 18:00 and 20:00.

Where is my mistake.
Thx for your help.

I gave out all results after another but have no clue why the result is null even with the right formatting in the form